# Form Submit to PHP

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am trying to submit data from an HTML form to PHP to be saved into mysql database. I had previously done this and for some reason it cannot work, I must be missing something.

This is Register page

```
<form action="reg.php" method="POST">
        <table >
            <tr>
                <td>Email :</td>
                <td><input name="Email" type="text" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password :</td>
                <td><input name="Password" type="password" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> </td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> </td>
            </tr>


        </table>
    </form>
```

This is the reg.php

```
<?php

include_once("db.php");

$SQL = "INSERT INTO  users  (Email, Password  ) VALUES ('".$_GET["Email"]."','". $_GET['Password'] ."' )";     

mysql_query($SQL);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
```

And this is the db.php

```
<?php

$MyUsername = "root";   
$MyPassword = "";   
$MyHostname = "localhost";      

$dbh = mysql_pconnect($MyHostname , $MyUsername, $MyPassword);
$selected = mysql_select_db("dbName",$dbh);
?>
```

If I run

> localhost/reg.php?Email=email@gmail.com&Password=123456

It does work and those values are shown in the database, I must be missing something in the register page.

It could be a stupid mistake as Im new to PHP.

Thanks in advance

Comment: try `INSERT INTO  users  (\`Email\`, \`Password\`  )`

Comment: Please ***PLEASE*** stop using `mysql_*` its an unsafe, old, flawed, unmaintained and (therefore) _deprecated_ extension. Learn to use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead. And use _prepared statements_. This code is about as dangerous as it gets (google injection attacks). Also: don't use `mysql_pconnect`. Persistent connections can (and if you're still learning) will bite you

Comment: anyways you need to do a post request, escape values  like` VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Email"])."','"`

Comment: You're using a POST method and `$_GET["Email"]` etc. = no match. Plus, you are very much open to SQL injection, in more ways than one. I hope this isn't a LIVE site, because you WILL get hacked, unfortunately. It's just a question of time, *really*.

Comment: You also need ID's on the input elements to make them hit the POST/GET arrays

Comment: @Kris.Mitchell no, you dont. The keys are generated by the name values of the input element

Comment: @user574632 I've always had issues just having the name attr on elements.  So I've always included the ID on every element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be using $_POST instead of $_GET

```
.$_GET["Email"]."','". $_GET['Password'] ."' )";
```

should be

```
.$_POST["Email"]."','". $_POST['Password'] ."' )";
```

When you type the URL in, that is a GET request which is why it works. You should really POST a form, because a GET will transmit the variables in the query string, and be visible. A password field is still plain text when it's transmitted.

Also, as has been mentioned, you're using deprecated methods for talking to the database and you're leaving yourself prone to SQL injection. Take a look at PDO http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

---

[**Use `mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements)

Also consider using [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function for password storage.

For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Storing what seems to be done in plain text, is not safe.

Comment: I am choosing yours as an answer because you directed me to a safer method PDO, which I have now used. The problem with the previous code was that I had an open form tag which I copy and pasted to get part of a template from another page. :/ Now I should make it with prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

You're making a mistake with the form method, change

```
<form action="reg.php" method="POST">
```

to

```
<form action="reg.php" method="GET">
```

If you want to continue using the POST method use

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO  users  (Email, Password  ) VALUES ('".$_POST["Email"]."','". $_POST['Password'] ."' )";
```

Comment: Although you're *technically* correct, it would actually be a *bit* safer if OP were to use POST instead of GET, considering is passing a password through an already unsafe form/method.

Comment: You're welcome. Make it as an edit though to outline OP's errors.

Answer (score 0):

debug you code and check the error you will get data in $_POST in reg.php . print_r($_POST) on your reg.php file you will get the data